# Difference between DateValue and CDate in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am working on a module to read in data from a spreadsheet and calculate values based on dates from the spreadsheet. I read in the variables as a String and then am currently changing the values to a Date using CDate. However I just ran across DateValue and I was wondering what the difference between the two functions were and which one is the better one to use.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`DateValue` will return only the date. `CDate` will preserve the date and time:

```
? DateValue("2014-07-24 15:43:06")
24/07/2014

? CDate("2014-07-24 15:43:06")
24/07/2014 15:43:06
```

Similarly you can use `TimeValue` to return only the time portion:

```
? TimeValue("2014-07-24 15:43:06")
15:43:06 

? TimeValue("2014-07-24 15:43:06") > TimeSerial(12, 0, 0)
True
```

Also, as guitarthrower says, `DateValue` (and `TimeValue`) will only accept `String` parameters, while `CDate` can handle numbers as well. To emulate these functions for numeric types, use `CDate(Int(num))` and `CDate(num - Int(num))`.

Answer (score 5):

`CDate` will convert a number or text to a date.

```
CDate(41035) 'Converts to a date of 5/6/2012
CDate("1/15/2014") 'Converts to a date of 1/15/2014
```

`DateValue` will convert date in text format (only) to a date.

```
DateValue("1/15/2014") 'Converts to a date of 1/15/2014
DateValue(41035) 'Throws a mismatch error
```

Answer (score 3):

Both CDate and DateValue, when used in vba, converts a value to a Date (dd/mm/yyyy format):
1)
    `LstrDate = "July 24, 2014"`
    `LDate = CDate(LstrDate)`

2)
    `LDate = DateValue("July 24, 2014")`

Both return the same result.

However DateValue returns the serial number of a date if used in application level (spreadsheet)

Comment: didn't know about the spreadsheet function, difference. Good to know.