# Having trouble comparing date value stored in a label.caption vs. now

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a date (format m/d/yyyy) stored in a Label1.Caption. I'm trying to run a simple condition to compare it to the actual time, but doesn't seems to work :/

My code is:

```
Label1.Caption = "1/5/2016"
If Label1.Caption > Now Then
'Do something
End if
```

Like this is it should be going into the if, but is not. Can you please help me out?
Cheers,
G

Comment: you probably need to convert the caption-string to a date-object using CDate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944662/difference-between-datevalue-and-cdate-in-vba

Comment: See [Excel VBA - Convert Text to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cdate can convert string to Date type

Cdate(Label1.Caption)

But 1/5/2016 is quite confusing, macro will based on date format setting in Computer to define, whether mm/dd/yy or dd/mm/yy.

Recommend, involve some text like Jan 5 2016 or 1 May 2016

Comment: This did the job. Thanks!